# Run length encoding of sequences

Tags: clojure

So I am trying to solve this problem, and this is the code I have come up with:

First I have a pack function, receives a list and groups same elements into a vector.

```
(defn pack [lst]
  (def a [])
  (def vect [])
  (cond 
    (empty? lst)
      lst
  :else
  (loop [i 0]
    (def r (get lst i))
    (def t (get lst (+ i 1)))
    (if (= r t)
        (def vect (conj vect r)) 
    )
    (if (not= r t)
     (and (def vect (conj vect r)) (and (def a (conj a vect)) (def vect [])))
    )
    (if (= i (- (count lst) 1))
       a
    (recur (inc i))
    )
  ))
)
```

for example if I have this vector:

```
(def tes '[a a a a b c c a a d e e e e])
```

pack function will return this:

```
[[a a a a] [b] [c c] [a a] [d] [e e e e]]
```

Then I tried doing the "encode" part of the problem with this code:

```
(def v1 [])
(def v2 [])

(conj v2 (conj v1 (count (get (pack tes) 0)) (get (get (pack tes) 0) 0)))
```

And it returned what I wanted, a vector "v2" with a vector "v1" that has the "encoded" item.

```
[[4 a]]
```

So now I try to make the function:

```
(defn encode [lst]
 (loop [index 0 limit (count (pack lst)) v1 [] v2[]]
    (if (= index limit) 
      lst
      (conj v2 (conj v1 (count (get (pack tes) index)) (get (get (pack tes) index) index)))
    )
    (recur (inc index) limit v1 v2)
 )
)

(encode tes)
```

but I get this error:

```
2021/03/07 00:00:21 got exception from server /usr/local/bin/lein: line 152:    
28 Killed                  "$LEIN_JAVA_CMD" "${BOOTCLASSPATH[@]}" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.easy=false -Dmaven.wagon.rto=10000 $LEIN_JVM_OPTS 

-Dleiningen.original.pwd="$ORIGINAL_PWD" -Dleiningen.script="$0" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" clojure.main -m leiningen.core.main "$@"
   
2021/03/07 01:42:20 error reading from server EOF
```

Any way to fix my code or to solve the problem more efficiently but still return a vector?

Comment: Never ever use `def` outside the namespace. There is `let` for what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`juxt` can be used in the `pack` function:

```clj
(defn pack [xs]
  (map (juxt count first) (partition-by identity xs)))

(defn unpack [xs]
  (mapcat #(apply repeat %) xs))
```

Comment: I always forget juxt! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

- Don't use [def](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/def) inside function, because it creates global
  variable. Use [let](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/let) instead.
- Don't use multiple [if](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/if) in row, there is [cond](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cond).
- Format your code better- for example, put all parentheses on the end together on one line.

Here is more efficient solution:

```
(defn pack [lst]
  (letfn [(pack-help [lst]
            (if (empty? lst) '()
                   (let [elem (first lst)]
                     (cons (vec (take-while #(= % elem) lst))
                           (pack-help (drop-while #(= % elem) lst))))))]
    (vec (pack-help lst))))

(defn pack-with-count [lst]
  (mapv #(vector (count %) (first %))
        (pack lst)))

(defn unpack [packed-lst]
  (into [] (apply concat packed-lst)))

(pack '[a a a a b c c a a d e e e e])
(pack-with-count '[a a a a b c c a a d e e e e])
(unpack '[[a a a a] [b] [c c] [a a] [d] [e e e e]])
```

Answer (score 4):

As a rule, whenever you reach for loop/recur, there are some pieces of the standard library which will allow you to get the desired effect using higher-order functions. You avoid needing to implement the wiring and can just concentrate on your intent.

```
(def tes '[a a a a b c c a a d e e e e])
(partition-by identity tes)
; => ((a a a a) (b) (c c) (a a) (d) (e e e e))
(map (juxt count first) *1)
; => ([4 a] [1 b] [2 c] [2 a] [1 d] [4 e])
(mapcat #(apply repeat %) *1)
; => (a a a a b c c a a d e e e e)
```

Here *1 is just the REPL shorthand for "previous result" - if you need to compose these into functions, this will be replaced with your argument.

If you really need vectors rather than sequences for the outer collection at each stage, you can wrap with vec (to convert the lazy sequence to a vector), or use mapv instead of map.

Finally - the error message you are getting from lein is a syntax error rather than a logic or code problem. Clojure generally flags an unexpected EOF if there aren't enough closing parens.

```
(println "because we left them open like this -"
```

Consider working inside a REPL within an IDE, or if that isn't possible then using a text editor that matches parens for you.